# Monaco font in Konsole

Tags: kde, fonts, konsole

I can't set Monaco font in Konsole but it installed in the system.

[image]

How can I set monaco as my terminal font?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A workaround**

Make a new or edit the current konsole profile. The konsole profile is saved to the ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/.

Here, making a new profile: Test. Konsole > Settings > Configure profiles > New Profile. The ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/Test.profile (font:Andale Mono):

```
[Appearance]
ColorScheme=Linux
Font=Andale Mono,9,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0

[General]
MenuIndex=2
Name=Test
Parent=FALLBACK/
RemoteTabTitleFormat=%h : %u
```

Editing the Test.profile, changing the font to the Monaco:

```
[Appearance]
Font=Monaco,9,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0

[General]
MenuIndex=2
Name=Test
Parent=FALLBACK/
RemoteTabTitleFormat=%h : %u
```

Closing all Konsoles, relaunching the konsole.

After this the Konsole text size for the Monaco font can be changed with the Text size slider.

[image]

Comment: Why do I have to workaround? How does Konsole determine whether the font is monospaced or not?

Comment: I had to edit: ./.local/share/konsole/Profile\ 1.profile